# Split REST API and message broker consumer

Tags: database, spring-boot, rest, microservices, messagebroker

I am designing architecture which should consists of following components: REST API (spring boot or quarkus), message broker(activemq or rabbitmq) and database (mongodb or postgresql). This architecture should handle audit related scenarios mentioned below:

1. **REST API is called to store audit trail:** in this case REST API transfers received message to message broker and consumer which is part of the REST API consumes message and store it into database
2. **REST API is called to retrieve audit trails:** in this case REST API goes to database in order to extract needed data

Currently I am a bit puzzled if I should split consumer and REST API into different components. Actually, which pros and cons I will have if I'll do this and which pros and cons I will have if I won't.

As for me Scalability can be one of the pros if I'll do the splitting of components above, but it is hard to generate something else.

Please advice some direction to go in order to understand this better

Comment: why not just use a broker? https://activemq.apache.org/rest

Comment: @codebrane I am not sure that got your question correctly, could you please explain for which purposes just use broker ?

Comment: instead of a REST service sending messages to a broker, let the client send to the REST endpoint of the broker queue directly

Comment: @codebrane I got your idea, thx for the advice, but the idea to have spring boot rest service on top of message broker is to have possibility to validate messages before they comes to the broker. Also, in terms of my question I would like to validate if I need split spring boot rest and consumer, actually it is not related to message broker

Answer (score 0):

Regarding splitting possibilities & scaling:

1. Both APIs go to the same database, they are of the same domain. This is why I would keep them under the same service - using the same database from different components is a microservices anti-pattern.
2. In case you are running this service in a containerised environment & have the option of dynamic scaling (up & down) then this might be a good option.
3. Another approach would be using CQRS pattern to create read-write separation that can scale differently, but be aware that this is more complex solution & is eventual consistent.